# Keeping track of sms sent in Android

Tags: android, sms

I'm noticing the tracking pending intents that I send out via the standard SmsManager in Android doesn't seem to retain the extra information in them. Example:

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
sentIntent.putExtra("value1", "foo"); // <- note this value
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentIntent, 0);

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(numberToSendTo, null, mMessageToSend, sentPI, null);

//... in the broadcastReceiver that catches the SENT intent ...
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    arg1.getExtras().getString("value1");  // <- nothing, no such key
}
```

Can someone test this out, was this behaviour intended and I am doing it wrong, or is this a bug to be filed for Android?

Comment: The code is wrapping intent object into PendingIntent Object. the code puts value in intent object and not pending Intent object. So I suspect in you onReceive method you are getting the same intent object or Object of PendingIntent Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the flag [`FILL_IN_SELECTOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FILL_IN_SELECTOR) when you create the PendingIntent (see the spec for [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for the flags and their general behavior). This should force the `PendingIntent` to take in all the top-level extras from the `Intent`.