# Android : How to launch Pending intent from another activity with extras?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, extra

I am facing some problem with pending intents. I have set some Pending Intents using Notification Manager. These notification launch an activity when user click on them. I put some extras with Intent used in pending intent. This works OK with notification click.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

Intent intentOptionDialog = new Intent(Safety_Check_Service.this, Dialog_Safety_Check.class);
    intentOptionDialog.putExtra("startID",startId);
    intentOptionDialog.putExtra("CheckInID", CheckInId);
    intentOptionDialog.putExtra("Frequency", Frequency);
    intentOptionDialog.putExtra("flagFirstShedule", true);

        stopID = (startId + 17);

    intentOptionDialog.putExtra("stopID", stopID);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Safety_Check_Service.this, DIALOG_ID, intentOptionDialog, 0);
```

But my problem is that I want to launch these pending intents from another activity. The pending intents are created. How can I lauch these pending intents from another activity and how can I get Extras that was set with the pending intent?

Please help me.

Comment: see this article http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-launch-pending-intent.html

Comment: I have seen this. But I don't have object of pending intent in service I cant access it. I have to creat a new one.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have 2 pieces here:

1. Try using the answer I gave at [Keeping track of sms sent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118242/keeping-track-of-sms-sent-in-android/10118475#10118475): add the `FILL_IN_SELECTOR` flag when you create the `PendingActivity` to force it to carry the extras with it.
2. Once you have the `PendingIntent`, you can just call the [`send`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send%28%29) method to fire it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add data in Intent before adding passing it to it with `PendingIntent`**

First create a intent and add data

```
    val pendingIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    pendingIntent.putExtra(PAGE_KEY, HOME.name)
```

Now create pending intent from that intent with flag **`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`** to update .

```
       PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, pendingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Now in launched activity onCreate method access it like this

```
  if (intent != null) {
            val pageValue: String? = intent.getStringExtra(PAGE_KEY)
            pageValue?.let {
             // do whatever you want

            }
```